# Tiny Tower demolished floors

Tags: tiny-tower

In Tiny Tower, can I get a demolished floor back?

I demolished the record shop before I realized I needed it for the missions and the Stellar Record achievement.

Will it ever reappear in an empty retail unit?  Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what Ashley Nunn has stated, I would like to add that it is now possible to select a specific floor to build (thanks to a recent update on iOS, that is. Unverified for Android users)

When you build a floor, where you would normally have to select "Retail/Food/Residential/Service/Recreation/Creative", they will now be labelled as "Random [type]".

Below this, there is an option to "Select Specific Floor", which will enable you to select the exact floor you want to build. It does, however, cost a fairly significant amount of Bux.

Answer (score 6):

At least for the current Android release, floors are assigned randomly, so it is not guaranteed that you will get the same floor back even if you assign the same floor type to that unit. You can try, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

On the recent Android update you are able to choose specific floors. However, I am not sure if your floor will be available in that list. The list does not have all the floors in the game and on my device, the cheapest floor is around 6 and the highest at 220. So as you can see the prices are purely random! Good luck!